# Paper towel gets completely dark after I wipe my Dutch oven

Tags: cast-iron, dutch-oven

I bought Lodge cast iron dutch oven a few weeks ago. I didn't season it right away since I kept it in a dry closet. Last week seasoned it with pure almond oil (because I read it somewhere it's slightly better than other oils) and an hour in the oven (500F). After I cooked with it, nothing was wrong with the food. Then I rinsed it with hot water and wiped with paper towel, and the paper towel got completely dark, and it didn't seem like the oil I used for the food.

So my question is: Is it normal ? Should I reseason it ? I thought maybe I should've done the seasoning for a couple more times instead of once, or I used too much oil for the seasoning.

Thanks in advance,
Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention what your meal was, but this may help...from the Lodge Cast Iron web site:

Occasionally when your seasoning works a little too hard with acidic foods or really high heat, you may notice some dark residue on your towel when cleaning. This is perfectly safe and normal, and will go away with regular use and care.